# How to modify the groupBy result in Lodash

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, lodash

How to modify my script, so in result there is no key "author" (I want to have only song and place)?
The songs' list looks like that (obviously I do not copy whole list)

```
const lp3 = [
    {
        author: 'Queen',
        song: 'Bohemian Rhapsody',
        place: 1,
        change: 0
    },
    {
        author: 'Deep Purple',
        song: 'Child in time',
        place: 2,
        change: 2
    },
```

and my script:

```
const exercise10 = _.groupBy(lp3, "author")
```

and the result is e.g.:

```
Pink Floyd': [
    {
      author: 'Pink Floyd',
      song: 'Shine on you crazy diamond',
      place: 12,
      change: 4
    },
    {
      author: 'Pink Floyd',
      song: 'Comfortably numb',
      place: 15,
      change: 7
    },
    { author: 'Pink Floyd', song: 'Hey you', place: 18, change: 11 },
    {
      author: 'Pink Floyd',
      song: 'Another brick in the wall part II',
      place: 21,
      change: 10
    }
  ],
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `Array.reduce()` or lodash's `_.reduce()` you can destructure each object, and take out `author`, and then group the objects:

```js
const lp3 = [{"author":"Queen","song":"Bohemian Rhapsody","place":1,"change":0},{"author":"Deep Purple","song":"Child in time","place":2,"change":2}]

const result = _.reduce(lp3, (acc, { author, ...o }) => {
  if(!acc[author]) acc[author] = []

  acc[author].push(o)

  return acc
}, {})

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.21/lodash.min.js" integrity="sha512-WFN04846sdKMIP5LKNphMaWzU7YpMyCU245etK3g/2ARYbPK9Ub18eG+ljU96qKRCWh+quCY7yefSmlkQw1ANQ==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

If you want to use `_.groupBy()` you'll need to group the items, and then map the groups with `_.mapValues()`, and map the items to omit `author`:

```js
const lp3 = [{"author":"Queen","song":"Bohemian Rhapsody","place":1,"change":0},{"author":"Deep Purple","song":"Child in time","place":2,"change":2}]

const result1 = _.mapValues(
  _.groupBy(lp3, 'author'),
  values => _.map(values, o => _.omit(o, 'author')),
)

// or using chaining

const result2 = _(lp3)
  .groupBy(lp3, 'author') // create the groups
  .mapValues(values => // map the values of the groups x
    _.map(values, o => _.omit(o, 'author')) // map the items
  )
  .value()

console.log(result1)
console.log(result2)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.21/lodash.min.js" integrity="sha512-WFN04846sdKMIP5LKNphMaWzU7YpMyCU245etK3g/2ARYbPK9Ub18eG+ljU96qKRCWh+quCY7yefSmlkQw1ANQ==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: unfortunately I can't use reduce, I have to use only lodash's functions... after groupBy I got blocked and I don't know how to change that..

Comment: Added a lodash answer as well.

Comment: Are you using lodash chaining or lodash/fp?

Comment: to be totally honest with you - I'm a student and had only one lesson with Lodash, just to get familliar with it, and had just to use documentation: at lodash.com

Comment: could you please explain how the result1 works? I do not understand that mapValues function even though I checked the documention I can't imagine how it works in our situation. I'd be grateful if you told me how it works step by step.

Comment: It maps the values of objects, so if you have an object `{ key1: val1, key2: val2, key3: val3 }`, mapValues would iterate the values (`val1`, `val2`, `val3`) of the object, and return new ones instead. So `mapValues({ key1: 1, key2: 2, key3: 3 }, v => v + 1)` would return `{ key1: 2, key2: 3, key3: 4 }`.